# Why is input() being ignored?

Tags: python, input

Why is the input() after the if statement not working?
I need some help, the input() after the if statement is supposed to stop the script, however it just continues. If i give it another command, for example print("...") or time.sleep(10) it will execute, it is only the input() that does not work. Any ideas?

Edit: Because it might not be clear what the intention is. When asking for an input after the if statement the script should wait before continuing. This is because I want it to pause after I move the mouse so that it does not keep spamming the keys, but I am able to resume it if needed.

```
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as KeyController
from pynput.mouse import Controller as MouseController

key = KeyController()
mouse = MouseController()


def f1_toggle():
    key.press(Key.f1)
    key.release(Key.f1)


def enter_toggle():
    key.press(Key.enter)
    key.release(Key.enter)


input("Press any key to start:")
time.sleep(5)
while True:

    start_position = mouse.position

    key.press(Key.ctrl_l)
    print("Ctrl pressed")
    f1_toggle()
    print("F1 toggled")
    key.release(Key.ctrl_l)
    print("Ctrl released")
    time.sleep(1)
    enter_toggle()
    print("Enter toggled")
    time.sleep(.5)

    end_position = mouse.position

    if start_position != end_position:
        input("Press any key to continue ")
```

Comment: the if statement doesn't make any difference, whether its true or false, you still continue the loop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you consider the possibility that the mouse didn't move in between `start_position = mouse.position` and `end_position = mouse.position`, such that the `start_position != end_position` condition isn't met? Aside from that, in your own words, why should this stop the script? It's not clear exactly what you expect to happen when this code runs, or why.

Comment: Is standard input the terminal?

Comment: @chepner I rather doubt that someone asking this question would understand what you're asking. However, there was no complaint about the behaviour of `input("Press any key to start:")`, so I infer that that isn't the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, the first input() works as supposed - it waits for a key to be pressed in order to continue, the second however does not.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `enter_toggle()` before you ask for input. This is simulating pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. This is being used as the response to the `input()` call, so it doesn't wait for the user to enter something manually.

Comment: You are right, it is indeed the enter. What I don't understand is that this should have been completely executed before even asking for the input so --> press key -> print that the key has been toggled --> wait .5 sec --> get variable, and only after that check the 2 variables and then ask for input. How is it possible that so many commands have been executed after that, but it still somehow affects the input?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the two variables are different?
2. I don't have `pyinput`, and I am using python 3.8, but in my computer, the input isn't skipped (I commented the `pyinput`).

Try this:

```py
try:
    input("Press any key to continue ")

except Exception as e:
    print(e);
```

Try to see if this helps and what it prints.

Comment: unfortunately, it does not.

I even tried 
    print("if statement works")
        input()
    else:
        print("if statements does not work")

and If I move/don't the mouse the text will be printed, but the script will ignore the input().